# FAST way to check image size in PHP

Tags: php, image

Is there an alternative to getimagesize() in PHP that runs faster? I'm trying to check the width and height of a lot of images (and only display the ones that meet the minimum threshold) and echo them to user. getimagesize() takes up to 30 seconds to process when I have a lot of images on the page.

Thanks!

Comment: Why not put together a cron script or something to store the image sizes in a database table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try imagesx() and imagesy()

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're working with too much images.

Try using [ImageMagick's](http://www.google.com.ng/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=image%20magick%20get%20image%20height%20php&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CB4QFjAA&url=http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php&ei=eCq0TunCCY_DtAan7tHSAw&usg=AFQjCNEDpaIsl7cteT4ddZ8kb42-vEx49Q) `Imagick::getImageHeight` and `Imagick::getImageWidth`